Explanation of the differential, with regards to the regularity condition in the definition of a regular surface
For a subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ to be a regular surface, there are three conditions, one of which is the following (called the regularity condition):

For each $q \in U$, the differential $d\mathbf{x}_q: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is one-to-one.

The following explanation is given for it in do Carmo:

I am quite confused about this explanation. My questions can be summarized as the following:

Why is the $d\mathbf{x}_q$ a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$? Why are we going up a dimension?
What is the map $u \rightarrow (u,v_0)$ doing? I'm confused by what it means to map $u$ to $(x(u,v_0), y(u,v_0), z(u,v_0))$. Adding on, what is the intuition behind a coordinate curve?
What is the difference between the maps $\mathbf{x}$ (a parameterization of coordinates in a nbhd of $p$), and $\mathbf{x}_q$? Are the domain and codomain spaces different?
What is the syntax in the phrase "called the coordinate curve $v=v_0$"? As in the coordinate curve is called $v=v_0$? But why is it called an inequality?
In general, can someone provide some intuition behind this regularity condition and why it is part of the definition of a regular surface?


For instance, if the map $\mathbf{x}$ is constant, its image is a single point and its differential will be zero (hence not one-to-one).
